# Django multiple databases - can't connect to mysql server fallback to sqlite

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

I have a django applicaiton with multiple databases.  The default database is on the local machine.  There is also a remote mysql database which is used for some write operations, but it is not always up.  When the server is down, mysqldb raises an OperationalError.

I would like have a local sqlite database called 'fallback' which would accept the data if the mysql server is down.  I realize that this involves at try/except clause in django.db.mysql.base, but I am not quite sure where to go from there.  Has anyone tried something similar?  Do you have suggestions on a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use [Database Routers](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) in combination with a custom base Model class that overrides the `save` method. Wrap it in a `try..catch`, and if the OperationalError occurs, provide some hints so your database router can determine if the fallback needs to be used.

I think this will be the cleanest way, rather than modifying the django code itself.

Comment: +1 for convincing me not to modify django code.  I didn't use routers due to the specific nature of the writes to the remote DB.  See my solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945295/django-multiple-databases-one-not-always-available/.  It hadn't been working, due a related error in a connection_created signal handler.

Comment: Routers does not deal with database connections and cursors (which are responsible of OperationalError).They just select a database alias, that's to say the key in your settings.DATABASES dictionary. Did you find an alternative way to test a database connection and select another one as fallback?

Comment: You're right @Marco. I'd, now, recommend doing a try: .using['primary'] except: .using['backup'] in the save method.